# How to pass query params in every single route path in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement React Router with query params like so http://localhost:3000/login?Id=1, I was able to achieve it only for my login route that too if I put path as http://localhost:3000/ which then redirects , however, I want to implement across the application. It matches `nomatch` route if I implement on other routes. This is how my `index.js` looks like, Can someone guide me how can i go about implementing all routes path including query params ?.

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path={`/`}
            render={() => {
              if (!store.getState().login.isAvailable) {
                return <Redirect to={`/login?Id=${Id}`} />
              } else {
                return <Dashboard />
              }
            }}
          />
          <Route exact path={`/login`} component={Login} />
          <Route exact path={`/signup`} component={SignUp} />
          {Routes.map((prop, key) => (
            <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />
          ))}
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify please, if a user visits any path, like signup or login, you want them to then be redirected to the same page, but with query params passed?

Comment: @ZekeHernandez,No i simply want every route to have query params.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways about to accomplish what you want.
The most basic way would be on each "page" or root component of each route, handle the parsing of query params.

Any component that is the `component` of a `Route` component, will have the prop `location` passed to it. The query params are located in `location.search` and that will need to be parsed. If you are only worried about modern browsers, you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), or you can use a library like [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#readme), or of course, you can parse them yourself.

You can read more in the [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters).

The second way of doing this, really isn't that different, but you can have a HOC that wraps around each of your "pages" that handles the parsing of the query params, and passes them as a list or something to the "page" component in question.

Here's an example of the basic way using `URLSearchParams`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// this is your "page" component, we are using the location prop
function ParamsPage({ location }) {
  // you can use whatever you want to parse the params
  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{params.get("name")}</div>
      // this link goes to this same page, but passes a query param
      <a href="/?name=MyName">Link that has params</a>
    </div>
  );
}

// this would be equivalent to your index.js page
function ParamsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route component={ParamsPage} />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default ParamsExample;
```

EDIT: and to clarify, you don't need to do anything on your index.js page to make this work, the simple `Route`s you have should work fine.

Comment: Further routes should include query parameters in the path. Like if we need to go to User component the URL should be like:  http://localhost:3000/login?Id=1/user